# Make file syntax error - missing separator

Tags: makefile

I am getting make file error on line 139 below at `$(eval $(RULES))`
I am really inexperienced in make file syntax.
This is is error it is giving me when I enter make command.

```
common.mak:139: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

I tried to removed the tab by single space, \t nothing works.
Do you know what can be the reason?

Thanks

```
#
# common bits used by all libraries
#

# first so "all" becomes default target
all: all-yes

ifndef SUBDIR

ifndef V
Q      = @
ECHO   = printf "$(1)\t%s\n" $(2)
BRIEF  = CC CXX HOSTCC HOSTLD AS YASM AR LD STRIP CP
SILENT = DEPCC DEPHOSTCC DEPAS DEPYASM RANLIB RM

MSG    = $@
M      = @$(call ECHO,$(TAG),$@);
$(foreach VAR,$(BRIEF), \
    $(eval override $(VAR) = @$$(call ECHO,$(VAR),$$(MSG)); $($(VAR))))
$(foreach VAR,$(SILENT),$(eval override $(VAR) = @$($(VAR))))
$(eval INSTALL = @$(call ECHO,INSTALL,$$(^:$(SRC_DIR)/%=%)); $(INSTALL))
endif

ALLFFLIBS = avcodec avdevice avfilter avformat avresample avutil postproc swscale swresample

# NASM requires -I path terminated with /
IFLAGS     := -I. -I$(SRC_PATH)/
CPPFLAGS   := $(IFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS)
CFLAGS     += $(ECFLAGS)
CCFLAGS     = $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS)
ASFLAGS    := $(CPPFLAGS) $(ASFLAGS)
CXXFLAGS   += $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS)
YASMFLAGS  += $(IFLAGS:%=%/) -Pconfig.asm

HOSTCCFLAGS = $(IFLAGS) $(HOSTCPPFLAGS) $(HOSTCFLAGS)
LDFLAGS    := $(ALLFFLIBS:%=$(LD_PATH)lib%) $(LDFLAGS)

define COMPILE
       $(call $(1)DEP,$(1))
       $($(1)) $($(1)FLAGS) $($(1)_DEPFLAGS) $($(1)_C) $($(1)_O) $<
endef

COMPILE_C = $(call COMPILE,CC)
COMPILE_CXX = $(call COMPILE,CXX)
COMPILE_S = $(call COMPILE,AS)

%.o: %.c
    $(COMPILE_C)

%.o: %.cpp
    $(COMPILE_CXX)

%.s: %.c
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -S -o $@ $<

%.o: %.S
    $(COMPILE_S)

%.i: %.c
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $(CC_E) $<

%.h.c:
    $(Q)echo '#include "$*.h"' >$@

%.ver: %.v
    $(Q)sed 's/$$MAJOR/$($(basename $(@F))_VERSION_MAJOR)/' $^ > $@

%.c %.h: TAG = GEN

# Dummy rule to stop make trying to rebuild removed or renamed headers
%.h:
    @:

# Disable suffix rules.  Most of the builtin rules are suffix rules,
# so this saves some time on slow systems.
.SUFFIXES:

# Do not delete intermediate files from chains of implicit rules
$(OBJS):
endif

include $(SRC_PATH)/arch.mak

OBJS      += $(OBJS-yes)
FFLIBS    := $(FFLIBS-yes) $(FFLIBS)
TESTPROGS += $(TESTPROGS-yes)

LDLIBS       = $(FFLIBS:%=%$(BUILDSUF))
FFEXTRALIBS := $(LDLIBS:%=$(LD_LIB)) $(EXTRALIBS)

EXAMPLES  := $(EXAMPLES:%=$(SUBDIR)%-example$(EXESUF))
OBJS      := $(sort $(OBJS:%=$(SUBDIR)%))
TESTOBJS  := $(TESTOBJS:%=$(SUBDIR)%) $(TESTPROGS:%=$(SUBDIR)%-test.o)
TESTPROGS := $(TESTPROGS:%=$(SUBDIR)%-test$(EXESUF))
HOSTOBJS  := $(HOSTPROGS:%=$(SUBDIR)%.o)
HOSTPROGS := $(HOSTPROGS:%=$(SUBDIR)%$(HOSTEXESUF))
TOOLS     += $(TOOLS-yes)
TOOLOBJS  := $(TOOLS:%=tools/%.o)
TOOLS     := $(TOOLS:%=tools/%$(EXESUF))
HEADERS   += $(HEADERS-yes)

DEP_LIBS := $(foreach NAME,$(FFLIBS),lib$(NAME)/$($(CONFIG_SHARED:yes=S)LIBNAME))

SRC_DIR    := $(SRC_PATH)/lib$(NAME)
ALLHEADERS := $(subst $(SRC_DIR)/,$(SUBDIR),$(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.h $(SRC_DIR)/$(ARCH)/*.h))
SKIPHEADERS += $(ARCH_HEADERS:%=$(ARCH)/%) $(SKIPHEADERS-)
SKIPHEADERS := $(SKIPHEADERS:%=$(SUBDIR)%)
HOBJS        = $(filter-out $(SKIPHEADERS:.h=.h.o),$(ALLHEADERS:.h=.h.o))
checkheaders: $(HOBJS)
.SECONDARY:   $(HOBJS:.o=.c)

alltools: $(TOOLS)

$(HOSTOBJS): %.o: %.c
    $(call COMPILE,HOSTCC)

$(HOSTPROGS): %$(HOSTEXESUF): %.o
    $(HOSTLD) $(HOSTLDFLAGS) $(HOSTLD_O) $< $(HOSTLIBS)

$(OBJS):     | $(sort $(dir $(OBJS)))
$(HOBJS):    | $(sort $(dir $(HOBJS)))
$(HOSTOBJS): | $(sort $(dir $(HOSTOBJS)))
$(TESTOBJS): | $(sort $(dir $(TESTOBJS)))
$(TOOLOBJS): | tools

OBJDIRS := $(OBJDIRS) $(dir $(OBJS) $(HOBJS) $(HOSTOBJS) $(TESTOBJS))

CLEANSUFFIXES     = *.d *.o *~ *.h.c *.map *.ver *.ho *.gcno *.gcda
DISTCLEANSUFFIXES = *.pc
LIBSUFFIXES       = *.a *.lib *.so *.so.* *.dylib *.dll *.def *.dll.a

define RULES
clean::
    $(RM) $(OBJS) $(OBJS:.o=.d)
    $(RM) $(HOSTPROGS)
    $(RM) $(TOOLS)
endef

$(eval $(RULES))

-include $(wildcard $(OBJS:.o=.d) $(HOSTOBJS:.o=.d) $(TESTOBJS:.o=.d) $(HOBJS:.o=.d))
```

Comment: When you edit a makefile in `vim`, make sure you do not have 'expandtabs' set; `:set noet` will cancel it.

Comment: I don't have access to vim. I am using MinGW in windows.

Comment: Make sure you really have tabs at the start of the action lines - recipe lines as MadScientist (and GNU Make manual) calls them.

Comment: I pressed tab key and saved the make file. Same error.

Comment: You may be running into a 'nice helpful editor' that changes tabs into blanks.

Comment: I replaced $(eval $(RULES)) with 3 lines after clean:: Basically I just have $(RM) $(OBJS) $(OBJS:.o=.d) $(RM) $(HOSTPROGS) $(RM) $(TOOLS) in 3 lines. But it now says missing separator in this line: $(RM) $(OBJS) $(OBJS:.o=.d)

Answer (score 6):

I experienced that same issue when trying to configure ffmpeg for `make`.
With the current version of ffmpeg's master branch the issue occurs for **common.mak** at line 160.

To solve this issue I tried the following steps:

- `git config core.autocrlf false`
- delete all `*.mak` files
- `git reset --hard`

These steps alone **did not fully solve** my problem. Based on the hints regarding the TAB (**\t**) characters I changed line 160 from

[image: original file from git repo]

**to**

[image: altered file]

Note the **arrow** (indicating a TAB) at line 160 between `$(` and `eval $(RULES))`.
This TAB solved the problem for me. I had to make this change to a further `*.mak` file. There was the same error message for another file. By the way, **Notepad++** is a great tool to insert a TAB as well as for changing the line endings.

Since ffmpeg takes a while for building I decided to share my solution...

Comment: Thank you for posting your answer, it was very helpful.

Answer (score 5):

I had this exact same issue - when also checking out FFMPEG on Windows *but using git*.

After running `configure` and when trying to run `make` I got the same line:

```
  common.mak:139: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

As suggested by @MadScientist - Makefiles are particularly fussy not just about tab (\t) but also the choice of line ending (**LF** vs. **CRLF**).

This is down to the GNU  `make` command which has to run them - which seems to only respect **LF**.

So a *nix version, such as this, will work:

[image]

And here is the same file under Windows, which won't work:

[image]

(Another giveaway is that it is also bigger with double the bytes at the end of each line!)

Bottom line (so to speak) is that you might have to reformat your files - perhaps by using the `dos2unix` command.

This would still be the case even if not directly cloning from git - but instead downloading a tar/zip that was itself created from a git clone. The end of lines would be preserved.

Or, if using Git (directly as I was) you have to tell it how to handle the end of line characters. When it checks-out/clones and when it commits.

There is a full description of what this means here: http://adaptivepatchwork.com/2012/03/01/mind-the-end-of-your-line/

And how it can be configured (for the old version of git) via the `[core].eol` setting.

This is also apparent on Windows, when if you run the installer (e.g. http://git-scm.com/downloads) you get a dialogue such as this:

[image]

Selecting the final option to "checkout as-is, commit as-is" fixed it for me. Not perhaps the most principled way, but it forced the LF endings to be preserved.

Comment: I had to `git config core.autocrlf false` and `git reset --hard` to get my ffmpeg to configure. Seems common.mak wasn't the only file with problems.

Comment: I had a similar problem. I fixed it by deleting ALL Makefiles and *.mak files, then doing a git reset --hard. Without the manual delete, git reset --hard was NOT resetting the files. (I'm guessing because git didn't think they had changed, because it was ignoring line endings?)

Answer (score 1):

In makefiles, recipe lines *MUST* start with a TAB character (TAB must be the first character on the line).  You cannot have one or more spaces at the beginning of the line, either with or without a following TAB.

I don't know what you mean by: *I tried to removed the tab by single space, \t nothing works*; that sentence doesn't make sense to me.  Hopefully the above paragraph will help you understand what you need to do.

Be sure you're using a text editor (not a word processor) and that your editor doesn't try to "helpfully" change the formatting in your files.

In general, unless you're more experienced with makefiles I don't recommend using the `eval` function, which requires a pretty clear understanding of the rules make uses for expanding variables and functions to use correctly.  I'm not really sure why you're using `eval` in the context of the `RULES` variable, anyway; why not just write the rule directly without `eval`?

Comment: This make files comes in the FFMPEG download package. How do I write the rules in 1 line - just one big line? Will it be OK for you to share that quickly?

Comment: I removed eval and keeping the 3 lines from the Rules. But now the first line $(RM) $(OBJS) $(OBJS:.o=.d) gives same error.

Comment: This error is also happening in other make files in the download package of ffmpeg

Comment: Are you running on Windows?  What editor did you use to make these changes?

Comment: I downloaded the ffmpeg tar ball from ffmpeg site. Looks like this problem only exists for new version of FFMPEG. If I unzip then I get the make files. All make files have this problem. The older packages don't have this issue.

Comment: Well, you didn't answer the question.  But since you're talking about unzip I'll guess you _are_ running on Windows.  In that case, note that some older versions of GNU make don't handle the DOS line ending format very well: they expect traditional UNIX line endings.  It's possible your version is older and your makefiles have DOS line endings (CRLF).  Anyway, I suppose you should ask on the ffmpeg support sites/mailing lists.  Good luck!